Deploying Vite react but it show build error due to import but in local it work fine
Here is folder structure
The code is working fine on local/local build - but I'm getting an error while deploying vite react app on vercel
Error during build:

Could not resolve "./components/navigation/navbar" from "src/App.jsx"
file: /vercel/path0/src/App.jsx
at getRollupError (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:395:41)
at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:391:42)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20006:24)
at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19966:26
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1`

Here is the eslint.config.js file:
import js from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";
import react from "eslint-plugin-react";
import reactHooks from "eslint-plugin-react-hooks";
import reactRefresh from "eslint-plugin-react-refresh";
import eslintImport from "eslint-plugin-import"; // Import the plugin

export default [
  { ignores: ["dist"] },

  {
    files: ["**/*.{js,jsx}"],
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2020,
      globals: globals.browser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: "latest",
        ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
        sourceType: "module",
      },
    },
    settings: {
      react: { version: "18.3" },
    },
    plugins: {
      react,
      "react-hooks": reactHooks,
      "react-refresh": reactRefresh,
      import: eslintImport,
    },
    rules: {
      ...js.configs.recommended.rules,
      ...react.configs.recommended.rules,
      ...react.configs["jsx-runtime"].rules,
      ...reactHooks.configs.recommended.rules,
      "react/jsx-no-target-blank": "off",
      "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
        "warn",
        { allowConstantExport: true },
      ],
      "import/no-unresolved": ["error", { caseSensitive: true }],
    },
  },
];

Here is app.js file:
import Navbar from "./components/navigation/navbar";
import Footer from "./components/navigation/footer";
import Routers from "./routers";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routers />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

I have kept all file and folder in lower case to deal with case sensitivity, also deleted module and package-lock.json multiple time

Sorry, there's not enough information here to really solve this. And the screenshot of the folder structure doesn't show if navbar and footer exists within the navigation folder. That said, in the cases I've got a similar problem, when it works when running locally and something fails with an import error when building and the config is correct, it usually have been because of a circular import.

Thanks for help, found the issue, it is due to the in window/mac file or folder name not case sensitive but in deployment it use Linux in which file name is case sensitive, i have changed file and folder name but it not tracked in git, we have to config git to get it tracked by using git config core.ignorecase false
